# How to make ammonia-resistant organisms through their biochemistry?

Tags: biology, xenobiology, hard-science, biochemistry

Its a very simple question really, yet the answers are obviously complex (like everything in biochemistry) how do I allow my organisms to tolerate ammonia yet still be carbon based by altering their biochemistry. Are nucleic acids and amino acids broken/degraded by Ammonia? what causes hyperammonaemia in Terran life-forms? The last post I asked was perhaps a bit broad and complex, but I've narrowed it down from a broad range of topics to just one. My solvent is an Ammonia-Water mixture (2-3% ammonia) and I want lifeforms that can at least tolerate it.

Comment: Is this a more narrow version of [your previous question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/189069/40609)? If so, please delete your previous question. A train-of-thought series of abandoned questions is just another form of discussion and that's not what we do here. Thanks.

Comment: Also, please [review the many questions on this site about ammonia worlds and life forms](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+ammonia+life+form) and be sure you're not asking a duplicate question.

Comment: Ammonia is broken down in the liver to urea. A highly efficient liver will help here. Ammonia interferes with potassium transport in the brain; a modified mechanism her would help. Excess potassium might help but can be toxic by itself. How high a llevel of ammonia are you talking about? https://biochemistrymedicine.wordpress.com/2014/06/28/why-is-ammonia-toxic-to-the-body/

Comment: @DWKraus well atmospheric ammonia content is close to 1%, The Water-ammonia solvent that my organisms use in place of water is around 2% Ammonia and the body content of ammonia is about 3 times that of Terran lifeforms (around 0.13 to 0.24 mg/dL)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a similar system that bacterium use currently to keep from being attacked by otherwise lethal bases/acids: a non-reactive lipid layer that doesn't allow for the importation of ammonia past the layer. Receptors or biological pumps can be used to import biological nutrients or water without allowing overly toxic amount of ammonia into the organism.